# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have "check_wifi_available" method in my MainActivity, which detectes specific SSID that starts with "SDF-"charachters. The method works well  there but I have the problem when I am out of the range I am still getting the last scan result though I am out of the range so I deceided to call it from my  call  from "ConnectionBroadcast" class but after short time the app crashes.

Error:

```js
<?php
04-08 00:13:25.412: E/AndroidRun04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2567)
04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:161)
04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4713)
04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at com.bustracker.MainActivity.check_wifi_available(MainActivity.java:82)
04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at com.bustracker.ConnectionBroadcast.onReceive(ConnectionBroadcast.java:44)
04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2552)
04-08 00:17:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  ... 10 more


?>
```

```js
package com.bustracker;


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ConnectionBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
  MainActivity wifi;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  if (intent.getAction().equals(
    android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {

   ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
     .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

   NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

   boolean isConnected = netInfo != null
     && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
   if (isConnected) {
    Toast.makeText(context,
      "The device is connected to the internet ",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } else {
    Toast.makeText(context,
      "Please connect the device to the internet.",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

  } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
    android.net.wifi.WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
   wifi = new MainActivity();
   wifi.check_wifi_available();
   
  }
 }

}
```

```js
        <receiver android:name=".ConnectionBroadcast" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code inside broadcast receiver is incorrect.You cant instantiate an activity object.

```
wifi = new MainActivity();
wifi.check_wifi_available();
```

You need to put whatever code is inside check_wifi_available() in onReceive.

Comment: The problem ist that the result of this method"wifi.check_wifi_available" will be displayed in the xml file with "textWifi.setText(a.toString());" and the textWifi variable is declared in the MainActivity class. How can I manage it too?